# Scrape a PDF and upload it to S3 in Django

Tags: django, amazon-s3, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, boto

I am trying to scrape PDFs from a website and upload them to an S3 bucket.  I have a working scraper that successfully downloads the file locally using beautifulsoup4, as well as a working script that uploads a file to S3 using Boto.  What I am having an issue with is a way to skip the middle step of downloading it locally and just downloaded it directly to S3.

Is there a good interface between scraping and uploading to S3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved my goal with this function:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection, Bucket, Key

def scrape_to_s3(filename, origin_url):
    remote_file = urlopen(Request(origin_url)).read()
    memory_file = StringIO(remote_file)


    conn = S3Connection(settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
    bucket = conn.get_bucket(settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)
    k = Key(bucket)
    k.key = "media/" + filename
    k.set_contents_from_file(memory_file)
```